# How can i take facebook pictures and put them into an iphoto album?

Tags: photos.app, facebook

I see that once i put in my facebook credentials, i can see that when i go into albums it shows all of my facebook albums (when i drill into the album i see it then downloads the images).

I can't seem to use any of these pictures for another album though.  I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestion on how I can include these photos into other albums, events, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as it says, you need to import them. Currently iPhoto is referencing them on the Facebook servers. So download them from there with your web browser and then import them to iPhoto.

Comment: thanks . .i would have thought that they would have made this integration more seamless.  don't see why they can't automate that step within iphoto

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple 2 step process to place facebook photos into iphoto.
Drag the selected photo from facebook to your desktop.
Have your iphoto open and drag the photo from desktop to the selected iphoto album. Boom done! If you don't want it to remain on your desk top, drag it to trash.